# How to disable Yarn from automatically formatting code

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I have a file that all of a sudden shows up as if I did some changes in it in the git. I am trying to run:

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

On the file that I want to discard all the changes. But, if I run the `git status`, it shows up again there. I have even tried to run the `git stash`, but same thing happens. The file constantly shows up as unstaged when I run `git status`.

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   packages/fp/src/support/SupportIndex.jsx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a").
```

I thought it could be Intelij reformating the code and rebuilding the file, but on further inspection this seems to be happening only when I run `yarn`.

```
yarn run dev
```

When I run it, it reformats the code in that file, so it always shows up as changed. I know there is a flag for yarn to not do that, but I can't remember which one it is or find it?

Comment: Did you use the full path for your file? *(sorry to ask, just to rule it out)*

Comment: Is this file tracked?

Comment: @RomainValeri  I did use the full path.

Comment: @JordiNebot yes, this file is tracked

Comment: can you print the output of git status?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git stash leaving modified files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119934/git-stash-leaving-modified-files)

Comment: Is the file something that Intelij or other IDE continually recreates? I get '.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml' being rebuilt.

Comment: This usually means one of two things: (1) there's a `supportIndex.jsx` or `SUPporTINdex.JSx` or some name that's the-same-but-different like this, and you're on Windows or MacOS; or (2) there's some line-ending setting that's not right.  I'd bet on case (1), which is more common.

Comment: @DavidZimmerman I think that is the problem, I think Intelij is formatting the code automatically but on further inspection it actually looks like yarn is doing that. I know there is a flag command for yarn for this kind of cases, but can't remember which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to disable yarn from formatting your code, you should run it with `--no-fix` flag.
In your case:

yarn run dev --no-fix

That sets the  `eslint-loader option 'fix'` to `false`.